# How to convert string in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

From http response I received an object like this:

```
{"[3, company1]":["role_user"], "[4, company2]":["role_admin"] }
```

The key is an array...Is there a way in typescript to convert the key

```
"[3, company1]"
```

in an array like this

```
 [3, "company1"]
```

?

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the key, which is an array?

Comment: because I received it like string...this is a string-> "[3, company1]"

Comment: The person below beat me to it.  If you want to convert the string to an actual Array, you need to split the string based on a separator, which in this case is the comma.  You need to replace the brackets with an empty string.  ```"[3, company1]".replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",")```.  You might want to split on ```", "``` (notice the space).  Or you can just call .trim() on the array elements.

Comment: Although the answers will work, I would prevent dealing with data like this. It is really error prone to manually "parse" fields. Actually, it probably is an issue in the API.

Comment: Will the key always be an array with 2 items?

Comment: @Christiaan It's the infamous value-value pair

Comment: If any of the below posts answers your question, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on its left.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Object.keys with map and transform the string to array with split

```js
let data = {"[3, company1]":["role_user"], "[4, company2]":["role_admin"] }

let keys = Object.keys(data)
  .map(
    el => 
        el.replace('[', '')
        .replace(']', '')
        .split(',')
        .map(el => el.trim())
        .map(el => isNaN(parseFloat(el))
            ? el
            : parseFloat(el))
    )

console.log("Keys: ", keys)
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/to38g6cb/1/

Comment: This produces `["3", " company1"]`. 3 is a string and company1 has a leading whitespace.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to convert the keys to?

if want to convert it to a normal array then the below should do.

```js
const httpResponse = {
  "[3, company1]": ["role_user"],
  "[4, company2]": ["role_admin"]
};

const convertedKeys = Object.keys(httpResponse).map(value => {
  let keyArray = value.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(", ");
  return [parseInt(keyArray[0]), keyArray[1]];
});

console.log(convertedKeys);
```

If the above is not what you wanted, please kindly rephrase your question again.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first and last character using `slice(1,-1)` and `split` the string at `/\s*,\s*/` (comma with optional spaces on either side).

Then convert the first part to a number and return the array

```js
const input = {
  "[3, company1]": ["role_user"],
  "[4, company2]": ["role_admin"]
}

const output = Object.keys(input).map(k => {
  const [n, comp] = k.slice(1,-1).split(/\s*,\s*/)
  return [+n, comp]
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been easier if the `company1` part were already quoted, so that you could just use `JSON.parse`.  In fact, let's just do that!  Put quotes around the `company1` part with search and replace.

```js
let key = `[3, company1]`;
let obj = JSON.parse(key.replace(/[$A-Z_]\w*/gi, '"$&"'))
console.log(obj);
```

Note: I'm guessing at what characters might be valid and went with something that looks vaguely like a JavaScript identifier.  `[$A-Z_]\w*` Obviously not commas and right square brackets, due to deserialization ambiguity.